# Why doesn't unicodedata recognise certain characters?

Tags: python, unicode, python-module-unicodedata

In Python 2.7 at least, `unicodedata.name()` doesn't recognise certain characters.

```
>>> from unicodedata import name
>>> name(u'\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: no such name
>>> name(u'a')
'LATIN SMALL LETTER A'
```

Certainly Unicode [contains](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm) the character `\n`, and it has a name, specifically "LINE FEED".

NB. `unicodedata.lookup('LINE FEED')` and `unicodedata.lookup(u'LINE FEED')` both give a `KeyError: undefined character name`.

Comment: same output on python `3.4.1`

Comment: Seems like the Unicode table has holes :-)

Comment: On my machine, using python3.4 `name('\n')` fails, but `'\N{LINE FEED}'` works as well as `lookup('LINE FEED')`. On python2 all fails.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: no, `\n` has no name (other than `<control>`). `LINE FEED` is an *alias* instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `unicodedata.name()` lookup relies on column 2 of the [UnicodeData.txt database in the standard](http://www.unicode.org/Public/5.2.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) (Python 2.7 uses Unicode 5.2.0).

If that name starts with `<` it is ignored. All control codes, including newlines, are in that category; the first column has *no name* other than `<control>`:

```
000A;<control>;Cc;0;B;;;;;N;LINE FEED (LF);;;;
```

Column 10 is the *old*, Unicode 1.0 name, and should not be used, according to the standard. In other words, `\n` *has no name*, other than the generic `<control>`, which the Python database ignores (as it is not unique).

[Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#other-language-changes) added support for [NameAliases.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.3.0/ucd/NameAliases.txt), which lets you look up names by alias; so `lookup('LINE FEED')`, `lookup('new line')` or `lookup('eol')`, etc, all reference `\n`.  However, the `unicodedata.name()` method does not support aliases, nor could it (which would it pick?):

> - Added support for Unicode name aliases and named sequences. Both `unicodedata.lookup()` and `'\N{...}'` now resolve name aliases, and `unicodedata.lookup()` resolves named sequences too.

TL;DR: `LINE FEED` is not the official name for `\n`, it is but an alias for it. Python 3.3 and up let you look up characters by alias.

Comment: :) ... Here is a screenshot of using pure py3.8, py3.9 interpreters, nothing installed, with the result I mentioned. https://imgur.com/I9bYX1r

Comment: I just realized, perhaps by saying "we have this issue showing", it would be understood as "the exact same issue with the same characters". Although I do mention a certain string, as in different characters seem to have this issue in later version. I guess it's just as more characters are defined over time, one has to guard against them in code.

Comment: @Mazyod: I misunderstood what you meant by your error message, I thought you meant you got an attribute error for the function `name()` on the module. You are getting a different issue: Python 3.8 and Python 3.9 bundle different Unicode standards, 12.1.0 and 13.0.0, respectively. See the [`unicodedata.unidata_version` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.unidata_version). `SMILING FACE WITH TEAR` is [new in Unicode 13](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts-13.0/emoji-released.html).

Comment: The characters 0000-001F and 007F-009F are Control chars, and unicodedata.name() lookup throws a ValueError on them.

Comment: @smci: yes, because all codepoints with a name that starts with `<` are ignored, no name is found and that results in a `ValueError`.