# What is the "^I" (carat capital-i) character in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

I pasted some text from a text editor (Atom) into IPython and it was rendered as I saw it on the editor, but some special characters appeared, too. These are light-blue carat capital-i's (`^I`). They seem to represent indentations. Indeed, when I search through the string by index slices, they show tab characters (`\t`).

What is this symbol's name? I tried to find it using `unicodedata.name('^I')`, but it returned a `ValueError: no such name` [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552786/why-doesnt-unicodedata-recognise-certain-characters).

If anyone knows where I can find a table of characters by their string representation that will save me a lot of time. The unicode.org source cited in the SO post above does not allow that. Something [like this](https://linuxconfig.org/list-of-python-escape-sequence-characters-with-examples), but with `^I`.

Comment: That seems like [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation). Python does not use those. This is likely added (and hidden) by your editor.

Comment: `^I` seems like an encoding issue.  For example, if you open a "Windows" formatted file, you may see `^M` instead of the newlines.

Comment: Apparently, `^I` is a "tab" character.  See: https://superuser.com/questions/301345/what-is-the-i-character-and-how-do-i-find-it-with-sed

Comment: ``^I`` is the same as ``\t``: [9 (horizontal tab, HT, \t, ^I)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)

Comment: Those are great answers. I especially enjoyed this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters. If you post any of your comments as answers I will accept them.