# Printing unicode character NAMES - e.g. 'GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA' - instead of 'α'

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I am testing function `isprintable()`. I want to print the Unicode NAMES of all characters in string `string.whitespace + unicodedata.lookup("GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA")`.

How to print the all the names - e.g 'SPACE', 'NO-BREAK SPACE', HORIZONTAL TAB, 'GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA.

```
import unicodedata, string

for e in string.whitespace + unicodedata.lookup("GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA"):
    print(ord(e))
    print(unicodedata.name(e))
```

I get error 'ValueError: no such name'

```
32
SPACE
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: no such name
```

Comment: Hmm, [it seems like that's by design](/q/24552786/4518341). It's not very helpful though. I'm pretty sure there's another question that covers how to handle that. Looking...

Answer (score 5):

As comments indicate, the Unicode database doesn't have names for every character, but `NameAliases.txt` does.  Below parses that file and returns an alias if it exists.  In this case, the first one found in the file:

```py
import string
import requests
import unicodedata as ud

# Pull the official NameAliases.txt from the matching Unicode database
# the current Python was built with.
response = requests.get(f'http://www.unicode.org/Public/{ud.unidata_version}/ucd/NameAliases.txt')

# Parse NameAliases.txt, storing the first instance of a code and a name
aliases = {}
for line in response.text.splitlines():
    if not line.strip() or line.startswith('#'):
        continue
    code,name,_ = line.split(';')
    val = chr(int(code,16))
    if val not in aliases:
        aliases[val] = name

# Return the first alias from NameAliases.txt if it exists when unicodedata.name() fails.
def name(c):
    try:
        return ud.name(c)
    except ValueError:
        return aliases.get(c,'<no name>')

for e in string.whitespace + ud.lookup("GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA"):
    print(f'U+{ord(e):04X} {name(e)}')
```

Output:

```
U+0020 SPACE
U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
U+000A LINE FEED
U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN
U+000B LINE TABULATION
U+000C FORM FEED
U+03B1 GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24552786/4518341) linked by [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68153407/printing-unicode-character-names-e-g-greek-small-letter-alpha-instead-of#comment120454525_68153407), ASCII control characters do not have official names in the current Unicode standard, so you get a ValueError when you try to look them up.

The `curses.ascii` module in the standard library provides a list of two character "names" for these characters,  corresponding to the name listed in the Char column in the ASCII table (as displayed by `man ascii`), but without the description.

So we can do this

```py
import string
import unicodedata
from curses.ascii import controlnames

for e in (string.whitespace + "\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA}"):
    try:
        name = unicodedata.name(e)
    except ValueError:
        name = controlnames[ord(e)]
    print(name)
```

giving this result

```
SPACE
HT
LF
CR
VT
FF
GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA
```

which is not ideal, but may be the best that can be done without using external resources, as done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68157301/5320906) excellent answer.